# Jetty 9.4: How to configure multiple servlets for the same pathSpec?

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

In my Java application with embedded Jetty I have two HttpServlets configured, say Test1 and Test2
I want to serve one of them based on the state of the application.

In order to simulate the state I've configured a form with 2 buttons on a test page:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Test</h1>");
        out.println("<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">\n");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"test1\" value=\"test1\" /><br><br>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"test2\" value=\"test2\" /><br><br>");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
```

And the change is done in post (Main.handler is the ServletContextHandler configured):

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getParameter("test1") != null) {
            Main.handler.addServlet(Test1.class, "/test");
            resp.sendRedirect("/test");
            return;
        }
        if (req.getParameter("test2") != null) {
            Main.handler.addServlet(Test2.class, "/test");
            resp.sendRedirect("/test");
            return;
        }
        resp.sendRedirect("/");
    }
```

When trying a button on the first try the right servlet is added and served.
But when returning to the test page and choosing another button or even the same button an Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /test
```

How can I dynamically serve multiple servlets for the same pathSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Servlet Spec does not allow this.

What you are looking for is the Controller pattern, where you have a single Servlet that controls what tasks to perform based on other criteria.

The Controller pattern is a super common and is used in large projects like Spring, Dropwizard, Struts, etc..